# LSTM history length vs prediction error

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, artificial-intelligence, keras, lstm

I use LSTM to predict next step voltage value in voltage time series signal. I have a question:

Why using longer sequences (5 or 10 steps back in time) to train LSTM does not improve prediction and reduce prediction error ? (it actually degrades it - see the figures e.g. results for sequence_length=5 is better than sequence_length=10)

testplot('epochs: 10', 'ratio: 1', 'sequence_length: 10', 'mean error: ', '0.00116802704509')

[image]

testplot('epochs: 10', 'ratio: 1', 'sequence_length: 5', 'mean error: ', '0.000495359163296'

[image]

(predicted signal in green, real in red)

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
import csv
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential
np.random.seed(1234)



def data_power_consumption(path_to_dataset,
                           sequence_length=50,
                           ratio=1.0):

    max_values = ratio * 2049280

    with open(path_to_dataset) as f:
        data = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
        power = []
        nb_of_values = 0
        for line in data:
            try:
                power.append(float(line[4]))
                nb_of_values += 1
            except ValueError:
                pass
            # 2049280.0 is the total number of valid values, i.e. ratio = 1.0
            if nb_of_values >= max_values:
        print "max value", nb_of_values
                break

    print "Data loaded from csv. Formatting..."

    result = []
    for index in range(len(power) - sequence_length):
        result.append(power[index: index + sequence_length])
    result = np.array(result)  # shape (2049230, 50)

    result_mean = result.mean()
    result -= result_mean
    print "Shift : ", result_mean
    print "Data  : ", result.shape

    row = round(0.9 * result.shape[0])
    train = result[:row, :]
    np.random.shuffle(train)
    X_train = train[:, :-1]
    y_train = train[:, -1]
    X_test = result[row:, :-1]
    y_test = result[row:, -1]

    X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))
    X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))

    return [X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test]


def build_model():
    model = Sequential()
    layers = [1, 50, 100, 1]

    model.add(LSTM(
        input_dim=layers[0],
        output_dim=layers[1],
        return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(LSTM(
        layers[2],
        return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Dense(
        output_dim=layers[3]))
    model.add(Activation("linear"))

    start = time.time()
    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")  # consider adam
    print "Compilation Time : ", time.time() - start
    return model


def run_network(model=None, data=None):
    global_start_time = time.time()
    epochs = 10
    ratio = 1
    sequence_length = 3
    path_to_dataset = 'TIMBER_DATA_1.csv'

    if data is None:
        print 'Loading data... '
        X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = data_power_consumption(
            path_to_dataset, sequence_length, ratio)
    else:
        X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = data

    print '\nData Loaded. Compiling...\n'

    if model is None:
        model = build_model()

    try:
        model.fit(
            X_train, y_train,
            batch_size=512, nb_epoch=epochs, validation_split=0.05)
        predicted = model.predict(X_test)
        predicted = np.reshape(predicted, (predicted.size,))

    print "done"
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print 'Training duration (s) : ', time.time() - global_start_time
        return model, y_test, 0

    try:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    txt = "epochs: " + str(epochs), "ratio: " + str(ratio), "sequence_length: " + str(sequence_length) 

    # calculate error (shift predicted by "sequence_length - 1 and apply mean with abs)
    y_test_mean = y_test - np.mean(y_test)
    y_test_mean_shifted = y_test_mean[:-1*(sequence_length - 1)] 
    predicted_mean = predicted - np.mean(predicted)
    predicted_mean_shifted = predicted_mean[(sequence_length - 1):]
    prediction_error = np.mean(abs(y_test_mean_shifted - predicted_mean_shifted))
    text_mean = "mean error: ", str(prediction_error)
    txt = txt + text_mean

    # Now add the legend with some customizations.
    legend = ax.legend(loc='upper center', shadow=True)
    ax.plot(y_test_mean_shifted[900:1000], 'r--', label='Real data')
    ax.plot(predicted_mean_shifted[900:1000], 'g:', label='Predicted')
    fig.text(0.4, 0.2, txt, horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', transform = ax.transAxes)
    plt.savefig(os.path.join('cern_figures', 'testplot' + str(txt) + '.png'))
        plt.show()
    except Exception as e:
        print str(e)
    print 'Training duration (s) : ', time.time() - global_start_time

    return model, y_test, predicted

# main
if __name__ == "__main__":
    _, y_test_out, predicted_out = run_network()
    #y_test_out_mean = y_test_out - np.mean(y_test_out)
    #predicted_out_mean = predicted_out - np.mean(predicted_out)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe because your time series at time t does not depend on your time series at time t-10. If you have a time series `(x1,...,xn)` and there is no link between `xn` and `xn-p`, there is no reason to use a step back of p.

For example if you want to predict the weather one hour ahead, you will not use a step back of  2 weeks. Why ? Because the weather of 2 weeks in the past has no influence on the weather right now. You will use instead the weather of the last hour (or last day).

Ps : I use this example of weather forcasting because there is to me no link between weather two weeks in the past and now. But maybe an expert in weather forcast would prove me wrong !

Cheers !